# How to clear terminal window in Apache NetBeans (Java)?

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm trying to clear the terminal after the user enters a value in it. When the program starts it prints out some choices and prompts the user. For example, when the user enters 1 and presses Enter I want all of the text in the console to be gone.

I've tried this:

Some text...

```
if(option == 1){
            System.out.println("\033c");
            System.out.println("New game");
        }
```

Comment: Generally speaking the "terminal window" in Netbeans is not the same as OS shell/terminal (it's just a `JTextArea`) so "console" commands won't work.  In general, you probably shouldn't care and in that case I'd probably just open a OS terminal and run the resulting Jar manually

Comment: Also consider supplying values via Project Properties > Run > Arguments.